# Stop Android Studio from auto-importing java.sql.Date

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java.util.date, date

How can I set up that Android Studio always imports `java.util.Date`? It ALWAYS auto-imports `java.sql.Date`, which I never use, which then always gives me errors later if I don’t explicitly check the import statements (which of course nobody ever does). It happens each and every time I do something like

```
Date d = new Date();
```

Which is a valid constructor for both. Is there some kind of import priority?

Comment: What do you call auto-import?

Comment: As an aside consider neither using `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are long outdated and have serious design problems. Today `Instant` and the other classes from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) are a more appealing choice. Yes, you can use them on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and turned out java.util.Date was in "Exclude from Import" list in Settings (Settings- Auto Import - Exclude from Import). Clear this list and IDE will be asking which lib to import. Clear the list, add a java.SQL.Date and IDE will be importing java.util.Date asking nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First see if there's not any import of `import java.sql.Date`. Or any other `Date` class (**Important**)

Then type `Date`, you will see drop down list, let android studio find all classes named `Date`. Then choose the one you require in your class.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. There is an IDE setting for "auto-import" that needs turned off

Comment: To be honest I like auto-import a lot. I can type fast and I like that I dont need t explicitly import something. Writing something like new Date() takes less than half a second. Manually importing it would take several seconds. If you are a professional developer these add up pretty fast and so I use a lot of shortcuts and auto-generators etc. My problem is that even though all my project files use java.util.Date Android Studio still insists on importing java.sql.Date in a new file...

Comment: Let google implement this intelligent sense for you :)